# Create a multidimentional array in HTML using name attributes without specifying keys 0, 1, 2

Tags: php, html, arrays, post

How can I create HTML multidimensional array

```
<input name="learner[][name]" value="John">
<input name="learner[][age]" value="17">
<input name="learner[][name]" value="Jomes">
<input name="learner[][age]" value="16">
```

and I am expecting this from `$_POST['learner']` in php when I send the data to the server

```
array[0] => array('name' => 'Johan', 'age' => 17);
array[1] => array('name' => 'James', 'age' => 16);
```

The current output is

```
array( 0 => 
   'name' => array(
      0 => 'John'
     ),
   'age' => array(
      0 => '17'),
   'name' => array(
      0 => 'James'
     ),
   'age' => array(
      0 => '16'),
  )
```

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  Can you elaborate as to what you are trying to do?

Comment: What dont you understand there @ga

Comment: @NtiyisoRikhotso: what is the output of `$_POST['learner']` ?

Comment: The output should be  `array[0] => array('name' => 'Johan', 'age' => 17);`

Comment: I'm asking what is current output, not what should be

Comment: NB: There is not such thing as arrays in HTML. This is purely a PHP feature.

Comment: @NtiyisoRikhotso take the time to edit your question and provide more detail as to what you are trying to achieve and somebody will be able to help you.  Your question is very confusing.

Comment: If not mistaken you want the INPUT fields to capture some data and turn in into array and send to php through post?

Comment: @D.V.D. true that

Comment: I have only passing familiarity with PHP, but couldn't you just have inputs like `<input name="name[]">` and `<input name="age[]">`, get your post data like `$name = $_POST['name'];` `$age = $_POST['age'];`, then just loop through the `$name` and `$age` arrays to create the combined output you are looking for (since the order of both arrays should be aligned if I am understanding your html structure)?

Comment: @NtiyisoRikhotso In this case you need JS or jQuery to get the values from your inputs - create JSON array and send it say with ajax or form action to your PHP